# Drawing Polylines using multiple coordinates in Android Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

I have multiple location coordinates in a file. It is stored in a `JSON` Format. I am reading them and trying to draw using the `for loop`.

These is the sample code given on the developer website

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
    .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
    .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

I am trying as below:-

```
        for(int i =0; i<contentAsJsonObject.size(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = contentAsJsonObject.get(i);
            try {

                    final String lat = json.getString("Lat");
                    final String lng = json.getString("Lng");

                if(i == 0)
                {

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))).title("Starting Point"));

                }

                String s = String.valueOf(i);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))).title("Location Point "+ s));
                mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))).color(Color.BLUE).width(5));
                msg.Log(lat + lng);

            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                msg.Log(e.toString());
            }

        }
```

How can I draw polyline with multiple coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare map instance as global variable, define `drawLine` method as below:

```
public List<LatLng> routeArray = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

for(int i =0; i<contentAsJsonObject.size(); i++) {
  JSONObject json = contentAsJsonObject.get(i);
  try {
    final String lat = json.getString("Lat");
    final String lng = json.getString("Lng");
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat.trim()),Double.parseDouble(lng.trim()));
    if (!routeArray.contains(latLng)){
       routeArray.add(lat);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
  }
}
drawLine(routeArray);


public void drawLine(List<LatLng> points) {
  if (points == null) {
    Log.e("Draw Line", "got null as parameters");
    return;
  }

  Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED));
  line.setPoints(points);
}
```